# After spring boot upgrade from 2.1.3 to 2.2.6, spring boot test fails to create MongoHealthContributorAutoConfiguration bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Had spring boot test-cases with the below annotations, which were working on 2.1.3 version.

Test class snippet of annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {...., MongoTemplate.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

However, after upgrading spring boot to 2.2.6, the test cases started failing with below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'mongoHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Beans must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthContributorRegistry(HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'mongoHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Beans must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Beans must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.AbstractCompositeHealthContributorConfiguration.createContributor(AbstractCompositeHealthContributorConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.mongoHealthContributor(MongoHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

Also, the POM doesn't have any use of sticky versions for spring-data or spring-cloud which might be causing spring library inconsistencies.

Comment: Adding `MongoHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class` to the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation made it work